# Rounding With Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, rounding

`massTotal` is printing out as a number ending in ".0" no matter what the decimal should be. The `massCounter[]` indexes are doubles. How do I make it round to the first decimal place, instead of to the whole number?

```
public static double massTotal(double[] massCounter) {
    double massTotal = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < massCounter.length; i++) {
        massTotal += Math.round(massCounter[i] * 10.0 / 10.0);
    }
    return massTotal;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I believe this question can answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java?rq=1 , specifically DecimalFormat

Comment: What's the point of `* 10.0 / 10.0`?

Comment: I think you meant to do `Math.round(massCounter[i] * 10.0) / 10.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Math.round` function is basically *rounding* everything, i.e.

> 1.5 -> 2
>
> 22.4 -> 22

So therefore when they all get totalled in the method, it will always be `x.0`, which is just printing a whole number as a `double`, showing the first `.0`.

What you could do, is to completely remove the `Math.round` and then print the result with using `String.format` and it will show you the output with one decimal place.

```
String.format("%.1f", massTotal(myArray))
```

Or even easier, if you are allowed to use Java8 capabalities:

```
double total = DoubleStream.of(myArray).sum();
System.out.println(String.format("%.1f", total));
```

[Online example](https://ideone.com/yWeqFD)